# ui-sref redirect to a url with a different port

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ui-sref

I have the following code in my template:

```
 <a class="menu-button" id="addBtn" ui-sref="board" />
```

And the home.js entry for the board state is the following:

```
.state('board', {
    url: 'http://' + $location.host() + ':11002/goToBoard'
})
```

However, the redirect is not done properly, because the port part is not considered at all. I also tried giving the entire path, but that failed too.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to use the $location service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't make sense to redirect to a url with a different port using ui-sref, because it is completely a different website. just use

```
 <a href="http://localhostorwhatever.com:11002/goToBoard"></a>
```

to get hostname dynamically you could use ng-href

```
<a ng-href="http://{{getCurrentLocation()}}:11002/goToBoard"></a>

$scope.getCurrentLocation = function(){return $location.host()};
```

you need to inject $location service to your controller for this

Comment: but how do I get the window.location.hostname in a href tag?

Comment: It might be better to have it be a static variable since host probably isn't going to change. That way it can be set when the application loads instead of being called every time it's needed.